# RxJS pipe Finalize operator not getting called

Tags: rxjs, angular6, angular7

```
import {
    Observable,
    BehaviorSubject
} from 'rxjs';
import {
    finalize,
    share
} from 'rxjs/operators'

export class someComponent() {

    public count$ = new BehaviorSubject < any > (0);

    public constructor() {
        this.shareResponse()
            .pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                    console.log('finalize called');
                }))
            .subscribe((event: any) => {
                // Do something
            });
    }
    public shareResponse(): Observable < any > {
        return this.count$.pipe(share());
    }
    public countChanged(event) {
        this.count$.next(event);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
    <some-tag(countChanged) = (countChanged($event)) > < /some-tag>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BehaviorSubject doesn't complete unless you complete it yourself by calling
`this.count$.complete()`. That's why finalize() is not happening, since it is waiting for Observable completion.

Have a look at the code example on StackBlitz, see [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-finalize-demo).

Comment: Added this.count$.complete() in the subscription block but still finalize is not getting called.

Comment: @su1212 Have a look at reproduction on StackBlitz. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do with the code above, but you can use `take(1)` before the `finalize()` operator inside the `pipe()` to force it to finalize after the first emmitted value.